# Showing old aspx pages on mvc router

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, url-routing, actionresult

There is a project works like:

```
/node.aspx?id=1
/node.aspx?id=2
```

I need to change it to:

```
/node/1
/node/2
```

I have providing new mvc project and here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult node(string id)
{
return View("~/node.aspx");
}
```

And this is my RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Such a code works fine, but on case adding "id", it's not works anymore:

```
public ActionResult node(string id)
{
return View("~/node.aspx?id=" + id);
}
```

Error:

> The view '/node.aspx?id=2' or its master was not found or no view
>   engine supports the searched locations.

**Is there any way to show old page like "aspx?id.." on the router?**

Comment: Can use one action name `node` with one parameter on action hit the requested you need to check and return respective view with full path of your project

Comment: use ViewBag like ViewBag.Id = id. Now you can read id value in your view.

Comment: @jishansiddique could you give me a sample please.

Comment: @RajeshG WOW, it's fantastic, thank you! could you please post this as answer. Also let me to know is there any problem with multi request from multi users on different id, again thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass data from controller to view you need to use ViewBag. The View method will only accept file name or file path and query strings not allowed.

So to pass the id from controller to view you can use ViewBag as below. Further you can read [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/viewbag-dynamic-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2) to use ViewBag

```
   ViewBag.Id = id;
```

Also,  ViewBag’s scope is available in Request Context so there will not be any issue with multiple request.